# Which is faster in perl, Parallel::ForkManager or threads?

Tags: multithreading, perl, fork

Threads are considered as lightweight processes. Will they actually run faster than an equal number of forked processes?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Write your program matching the problem domain. You might not even have a bottleneck in threads versus processes.

Comment: Are you having a problem with your code running too slowly? If not then there is nothing to fix. If so then there are many places to look other than the multiprocessing mechanism.

Answer (score 6):

> Threads are considered as lightweight processes.

Oh no, they are not. The Perl threading model is intertwined with `fork` mocking on Windows systems. In many respects, spawning a new thread in Perl behaves the same as forking off a new process: Both resulting control flows run in *seperate* perl interpreters. That is, the whole program state is *copied* to make a new interpreter.

> Will they actually run faster than an equal number of forked processes?

Not likely. Spawning a new thread is software-side, and done by perl. Forking is done by the OS (on *nix systems) which can make use of copy-on-write techniques. This can make forking much cheaper. A small test:

```
$ time perl -Mthreads -e'threads->new(sub{threads->exit})->detach for 1 .. 5E3'
real    0m10.651s
user    0m16.421s
sys     0m1.904s
$ time perl -Mthreads -e'fork || exit  for 1 .. 5E3'
real    0m2.347s
user    0m0.032s
sys     0m0.516s
```

This spawns five thousand threads/processes. As it was tested on Linux, spawning a new process turns out to be faster. This may not be the case on other OSes.

This is not to say that Perl threads would be useless: They provide many benefits like optionally shared data, queues to pass data around, semaphores to manage shared resources, threads can return values etc.. The easiest way to share data betwen processes (without using modules) is the `pipe` builtin which creates two linked filehandles.

---

Do not confuse different interpretation of the word *thread* which each other:

- *kernel threads* are hardware-level execution lines. They are not generally scheduled, but run in parallel. Each processor has at least one thread.
- *OS threads* are provided by the operating system. Modern OSes schedule thread execution themselves (preemptive scheduling). Generally, all data is shared, the threads just have different stacks. Perl threads choose not to emphasize shared properties.
- Software threads, also *green threads* are scheduled by the software itself, often by cooperative scheduling. Many languages with cheap threads choose this model, e.g. Go. Two green threads do not neccessarily run in parallel. Coroutines and green threads effectively are related concepts: both describe *concurrent* execution paths.

  Software threads can sometimes run faster than OS threads because the software can make *context switches* at convenient places in the program. (Preemptive switching between OS threads or processes is more expensive, as the OS kernel has to run on regular intervals, and the processor cache and registers will have to be updated with data of another thread on each context switch. This does not matter much when writing regular application code)

  Perl threading does not generally use this model, however a module for coroutines exists ([`Coro`](https://metacpan.org/module/MLEHMANN/Coro-6.31/Coro.pm)).

Comment: "Oh no, they are not. The Perl threading model is intertwined with fork mocking on Windows systems." Not it's not. `fork` uses threads on Windows, not the other way around.

Comment: Your benchmark is ridiculously worthless. Your conclusion that forking is faster cannot be drawn from it. 1) That's a very very poor threading model, so you're not testing threads, you're threading bad code. 2) fork has many costs other than the up front cost.

Comment: @ikegami IIRC, support for the `fork` builtin on Windows is implemented via threads. Wasn't that code in perl partially reused for threading support, thus carrying fork-like semantics into the Perl threading model? Yes, that benchmark doesn't consider the indirection that the `threads` module implies. But I don't understand how it doesn't show that *starting* a parallel computation is cheaper via `fork`, on my specific perl/OS/PC combination.

Answer (score 3):

The [threads](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?threads) and [forks](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?forks) module provide the same interface. You can switch between worker threads and worker processes by changing a single word in your program. Test it yourself.

The difference is going to be eclipsed by how you use threads/forks. Misuing them can slow down your program enormously.

Comment: I do not intend to share any data between the parallel processes(or, threads). Would this piece of information change anything?

Comment: Makes me wonder why you're using either.